# Codeigniter: Cannot modify header information

Tags: codeigniter

I am getting following message when I click on a submit form button. 
What do I need to do to get rid of the error?

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output       started at /home/httpd/vhosts/handball-profile.com/httpdocs/cucc/cuccioletto_ci/application/controllers/admin_home.php:2)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 543
```

Comment: Show this controller admin_home.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Hi, I added ob_start() in the index file. Now I am not getting the message.